how does "A New Approach to Preserving Data Confidentiality in the Cloud" work?
I'm trying to implement a fracturing algorithm by Federal University of Ceara students I read in an IT magazine. The article with the title mentioned in my question submitted by Eliseu C. Branco Jr. et al is about taking a file and splitting it into 3 distinct files where none by itself can reveal information about the original file. I.E. it's encryption of the file in such a way that you get 3 files with 2 being slightly more than one eight in size compared to the third. Then any file can be submitted/stored by insecure means and the 2 other files then will be the key for decryption when taken together. None of these "keys" taken on their own can reveal information about the original file, and even 2 keys taken together still will not be sufficient to get all the information back. Thereby a 2nd file can be also transmitted/stored through insecure channels in such a way that when one way of transmission/storage is compromised the other transmission/storage wont...
The method used starts with a buffer 256 bytes labeled as $Obj_k$ with $k$ being the offset of the block this buffer is storing. Then Qba is a bitfield of 256 bits with bit being set if and only if the byte corresponding to the bit's position is present. Sba is a bitfield of 256 bits where for each bit set in Qba the number of repetitions of that corresponding byte-value is compared to 2: Bit is set if and only if that amount is larger-equal to 2, the remaining bits are cleared. Finally $M_{all}$ is an array of 256 bytes created out of an array M of as many lists as Qba has bits set. Each of those lists has the position of the corresponding byte-value in the 256byte buffer, sorted in ascending order. $M_{all}$ concatenates those lists and whenever last element of a list is reached, it's stored before the one already stored. With the help of Sba that can then be reverted and the finished $M_{all}$ informs of the actual quantities.
That's basically the algorithm in the article, it's even written out in the pseudo-language of computer-science articles. However, $M_{all}$ does kind of give away the game if you assume some good distribution of letters you can guess the text. For that reason the article literally writes:

To prevent disclosure of this information the elements of $M_{all}$ are
permuted using Qba and Sba like sort keys, generating $MP_{all}$.

what is a good way to implement that? never heard of the notion "permuted using 2 bits like sort-keys", what did the article mean by that? to clarify the article added something matrix-alike:
$MP_{all}=\left(\begin {matrix}
M_{all} (iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & M_{all}(iOBJ_k )_{256}\\
 Qba , Sba (iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & Qba , Sba (iOBJ_k )_{256}
\end {matrix}\right)$
$QPba=\left(\begin {matrix}
 Qba(iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & Qba(iOBJ_k )_{256}\\
MP_{all} (iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & MP_{all}(iOBJ_k )_{256}
\end {matrix}\right)$
$SPba=\left(\begin {matrix}
 Sba(iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & Sba(iOBJ_k )_{256}\\
MP_{all} (iOBJ_k )_1 & ... & MP_{all}(iOBJ_k )_{256}
\end {matrix}\right)$
Looks like writing a permutation, except normally when writing permutations in 2 rows the 1st row has ascending numbers and 2nd row has a valid permutation of those numbers. Here instead first row lists an array and for $MP_{all}$ 2nd assigns to those tiny numbers 0-3 composed of 2 bits? Anybody seen that kind of notation? I'm assuming the latter 2 mean that the bits are permutated according to the new $MP_{all}$ permutation. But how should I read the first?
I suspect what this is doing is group $M_{all}$ into 4 parts and then list those parts in the order they'd appear. Is there a better way to hide the information of M by using Qba and Sba? Please note that after that similar is done by encoding Qba and Sba as denoted above, with the help of $MP_{all}$, and then $MP_{all}$ is further obfuscated with 3-bit lehmer code relying on the fact it's still just a permutation, and then it's further hidden with the help of xor...
I know this is a lot of questions, but answering either of them is already a valid reply! As is pointing me to an actual implementation of the full algorithm. I need something to start implementing! What exactly am I being advised to do in this middle-part of the algorithm!?
